# Facebook Login- Redirect URL with hash token not accepting

Tags: java, facebook, redirect, gwt

I am working on a GWT project and trying to use Facebook login in our website. GWT has a feature to create history through history the hash token thing(#). The urls we create our like *www.example.com/#!signin* to make it crawlable.

**PROBLEM :-**

> Few months before Facebook developer console doesn't ask for the
>   REDIRECT URL It used to work with the redirect url that was given in
>   the code in the same format like above url.
>
> But the issue is its now asking on the developer console in the
>   facebook login setting.
>
> The normal testing project are working fine with the urls without #!
>   but the url like www.example.com/#!signin are not working. Can't understand the problem.

I have just replaced the redirect url with the one with a hash token(#!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. For Facebook login we don't need to give the tokens of the url in the redirect uri of Facebook developer console. We can just put the root address like only www.example.com/ .After that the Code will check through the history listener class.  We have to give the token of the redirect class in the code to create the url .